# socket connection between my mobile Android device and my PC

Tags: android, sockets, android-networking

I want to establish a socket connection between my mobile Android device and my PC, so that a string will be sent from my mobile phone to the Android application running on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial for setting up a TCP connection, which is probably the one you're looking for, based on Java in the PC side which might be the server or the client:
[Link](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html)

For more basic information about coding a client-server software you can also check this [series of YouTube tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr02nyPqLBU)